# brew doctor errors - safe to remove files?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, file-management, homebrew

It seems that I made a mess as the **brew doctor** returns a number of errors:

```
brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W3
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W6
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuProN-W3
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuProN-W6
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuStd-W8
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuStdN-W8
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMaruPro-W4
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMaruProN-W4
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinPro-W3
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinPro-W6
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinProN-W3
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraMinProN-W6
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraginoSansGB-W3
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraginoSansGB-W6
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuMin-Demibold
    /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/YuMin-Medium
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbdiff.1
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbedit.1
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/bbfind.1

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.10.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s_x86_64.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.2.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
    /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
    /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
    /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl.h
    /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
    /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
    /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
    /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
    /usr/local/include/tcl.h
    /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
    /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
    /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
    /usr/local/include/tk.h
    /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
    /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.la
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.la
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
    /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a

Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated.
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours. This is a long time in brewland!
To update Homebrew, run `brew update`.
```

## Questions

I've two questions:

1. Is it safe to delete all of those files?
2. If so, how can I do automatically, just by passing the file list?